# Can't create a hotspot from windows 10 after upgrading from windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

After I upgraded to windows 10 from windows 8, I can't create a wi-fi hotspot (using Virtual Wi-Fi Router). I get an error **"the group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation"** upon trying to create the hotspot.

Running **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit** on **HP ab032tx**.

---

I've tried this way on **Administrator: Command prompt**:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
>
> (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=AdHoc key=password
>
> The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
>
> The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
>
> The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
>
> The hosted network couldn't be started.
>
> The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible cause for this problem is that "Virtual Wi-Fi Router" isn't supported on Windwos 10.

Have you tried it with other software or tools like ... [alternativeto Virtual Wi-Fi Router](http://alternativeto.net/software/virtual-wifi-router/)

Also good to know is that you don't need any additional tools to create hotspot via Windwos 10. [Here](http://lifehacker.com/turn-your-windows-10-computer-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-1724762931) are simple steps how to create hotspot using using the windwos command promt.

Comment: after trying the third step of the second link you provided, i get **The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.**

Comment: Can you plz give me more information about what kind of error/problem do you get? Also have you tried it with another software similar to Virtual Wi-Fi Router?

Comment: I will add it to the Question.

Comment: apparently connectify.me software worked

Comment: Did you tried to troubleshoot this problem like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1gmKEyiFCk

Comment: yes I have created cmd in admin mode(I mentioned it in the question itself). Following the video, I don't have my PC in flight mode and following the second fix, I can't fid any "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter".

Comment: Then you need to try to trobleshoot this problem with other methods. https://www.google.co.uk/#q=windows+10+hotspot+The+hosted+network+couldn%27t+be+started.

Comment: But if the way with the alternative software has helped you, plz don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

is shown if the wifi interface is disabled. Enable it to resolve the problem.